# Displaying Video file from storage with MediaStore in android Java

Tags: java, android

I Used [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) to scan and display media files from my storage using below code

```
private void displayAllVideos() {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
    int column_index_data,thum;

    String absolutePathThumb;
    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};

    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,orderBy);
    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    thum = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        Log.d("VIDEO", cursor.getString(0));
        absolutePathThumb = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        Uri thumbUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(absolutePathThumb));
        //String cursorThumb = cursor.getString(thum);
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(absolutePathThumb);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(absolutePathThumb);
        String duration = getDuration(absolutePathThumb);
        VideoModel videoModel = new VideoModel();
        videoModel.setDuration(duration);
        videoModel.setVideo_uri(thumbUri.toString());
        videoModel.setVideo_path(absolutePathThumb);
        videoModel.setVideo_name(fileName);
        videoModel.setVideo_thumb(cursor.getString(thum));
        if (extension!=null){
            videoModel.setVideo_extension(extension);
        }else {
            videoModel.setVideo_extension("mp4");
        }
        if (duration!=null){
            videoModel.setDuration(duration);
        }else {
            videoModel.setDuration("00:00");
        }
        arrayListVideos.add(videoModel);
    }
```

with above code i can able to get and display video file, Is there anything i need to improve in my code.

Your help in need thanks in advance.android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no big issues with your method, but I noticed something that can be improved:

**Variable declaration**

In Java is not common to declare the variables at the beginning of the method:

```java
Uri uri;
Cursor cursor;
VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
int column_index_data,thum;

String absolutePathThumb;
```

Declare and initialize variables in the same place, it's easier to read and maintain.

By the way, `videoAdapter` is declared but never used, that's another reason why you should avoid doing this.

**Query results not used**

Here you configure the projection:

```java
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};
```

But after the query you never use the results for `MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` and `MediaStore.Video.Media._ID`.

**Close the resources**

The `Cursor` object which is returned from the query is a resouce that needs to be closed:

```java
cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,orderBy);
```

To close it automatically use the `try-with-resources` statement:

```java
try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,orderBy)) {                    
// ...
}
```

**Camelcase instead of underscore**

From the [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#367):

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
> lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

So instead of `videoModel.setVideo_uri()` use `videoModel.setVideoUri()` or even better `videoModel.setUri()`. Similarly for the other methods.

**Duplicated assignment**

`videoModel.setDuration(duration)` is called three times. Compute the value of `duration` first and add it to `videoModel` only once.

**Ternary operator instead of if-else**

Sometime using the ternary operator is better for readability. For example instead of:

```java
if (extension!=null){
    videoModel.setVideo_extension(extension);
}else {
    videoModel.setVideo_extension("mp4");
}
```

You can get the same result with:

```java
String extension = extension != null ? extension : "mp4";
videoModel.setVideo_extension(extension);
```

**Documentation**

In the link you posted there is an [example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#query-collection) that is very similar to your use case. Most of my suggestions are already mentioned there, read it carefully.

Comment: hi, i was not able to retrieve some video files ?. any help